# New-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem 'User-Agent' header must be modified error

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-lake

I'm trying to use powershell the create some new folder within Azure Data Lake Store Gen 1, but both New-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem and New-AZDataLakeStoreItem return errors.

I have RWX permissions on the whole ADLS, and I have PS version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision

---

5      1      17134  590

when I run

```
Test-AzDataLakeStoreAccount -Name "weudevpocdtl"
```

I get a True responce.

however, when I run:

```
New-AZDataLakeStoreItem  -Account "weudevpocdtl" -Path "/PowerShellTest" -Folder
```

I get the error:

```
New-AZDataLakeStoreItem : Error in getting metadata for path /PowerShellTest.
Operation: GETFILESTATUS failed with   Unknown Error: The 'User-Agent' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.
Parameter name: name Source: System StackTrace:    at System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.ThrowOnRestrictedHeader(String headerName)
   at System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.Set(String name, String value)
   at Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.Store.WebTransport.AssignCommonHttpHeaders(HttpWebRequest webReq, AdlsClient client, RequestOptions req, String token, String opMethod, IDictionary`2 
customHeaders, Int32 postRequestLength)
   at Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.Store.WebTransport.<MakeSingleCallAsync>d__22.MoveNext().
.
Last encountered exception thrown after 5 tries. [The 'User-Agent' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.
Parameter name: name,The 'User-Agent' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.
Parameter name: name,The 'User-Agent' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.
Parameter name: name,The 'User-Agent' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.
Parameter name: name,The 'User-Agent' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.
Parameter name: name]
[ServerRequestId:]
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AZDataLakeStoreItem  -Account "weudevpocdtl" -Path "/PowerS ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzDataLakeStoreItem], AdlsException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataLakeStore.NewAzureDataLakeStoreItem
```

and when I run

```
New-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem  -Account "weudevpocdtl" -Path "/PowerShellTest" -Folder
```

I get error:

```
New-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem : Method 'get_SerializationSettings' in type 'Microsoft.Azure.Management.Internal.Resources.ResourceManagementClient' from assembly 
'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem  -Account "weunappocdtl" -Path "/P ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem], TypeLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.TypeLoadException,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataLakeStore.NewAzureDataLakeStoreItem
```

On a different tenant, I used to be able to execute these commands and it all worked.

What am I doing wrong?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Data Lake Team ,See the [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/8141#issuecomment-447525703)- This is a problem with Httpwebrequest class used by our SDK. Setting useragent for httpwebrequest is different across netframework and netcore:

```
NET framework: webReq.UserAgent = client.GetUserAgent();

net standard webReq.Headers["User-Agent"] = client.GetUserAgent()
```

If you try to later thing in net framework you get the error you are getting above.

When you use this az module which is using the netstandard dll of our SDK. When you use that from windows powershell, its trying to use net standard dll on netframework which gives this error.

Solution:

I tested this in net core powershell. It runs fine.
We are moving from httpwebrequest to httpclient which will probably fix the issue.

So basically if you are using windows powershell use azurerm or else use Az from powershell netcore.

same error has been reported , here is the link for the the GitHub known issue.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/8141

I would suggest you to use Powershell core ,
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-windows?view=powershell-6

It should work then

```
Get-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem -Account "AccountName" -Path "/"
New-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem -Account "AccountName" -Path "/Staging" -Folder
```

Comment: In PowerShell how can we add the user agent?